# Order a data set by using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a data looks like below.

```
Name,colA,colB
A,1,100
B,2,102
C,2,101
D,2,103
E,3,99
```

I'd like to order the column firstly by colA and then by colB.

If the number in colA is the same, then the order will be decided by colB.

But if the order of colB cannot consistent with colA, then the row required to be removed.

Which the result I will see is...

```
Name,colA,colB
A,1,100
C,2,101
B,2,102
D,2,103
## E row is removed, as the order of colA and colB cannot consistent.
```

Does anyone know what is the elegant way to do so by using pandas please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and remove all rows where difference is not `1` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['colA', 'colB'])
print (sorted_df)
  Name  colA  colB
0    A     1   100
2    C     2   101
1    B     2   102
3    D     2   103
4    E     3    99

m = sorted_df['colB'].diff().fillna(1)
print (m)
0    1.0
2    1.0
1    1.0
3    1.0
4   -4.0
Name: colB, dtype: float64

mask = m !=  1
print (mask)
0    False
2    False
1    False
3    False
4     True
Name: colB, dtype: bool

print (sorted_df[~mask])
  Name  colA  colB
0    A     1   100
2    C     2   101
1    B     2   102
3    D     2   103
```

All together:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['colA', 'colB'])
print (sorted_df[~(sorted_df['colB'].diff().fillna(1) != 1)])
  Name  colA  colB
0    A     1   100
2    C     2   101
1    B     2   102
3    D     2   103
```

Comment: Sure, but then sort values twice - `print (df.sort_values(['colA', 'colB'])[~(df.sort_values(['colA', 'colB'])['colB'].diff().fillna(1) != 1)])
`

Comment: but how about if colB is not a sequence number (plus a consistent number), I mean, for example, the number is 100, 178, 203, 425, 9242 etc....., not 100, 101, 102, 103...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe use `print (sorted_df[~(sorted_df['colB'].diff().fillna(1) - 1 < 0)])`

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like it does not work at all...I saw many NaN in the output.

Comment: If sorts `NaN` values are in the end.But it seems very complicated. Can you add some data to question?